# Using a function to print an input one letter at a time

Tags: python

I am making a game/quiz in Python, but ran into a small issue. I made a function to print one letter at a time, but when I use that function for an input, it does not work and prints all at once. I've tried making a string for the input and multiple other things. To fix this temporarily, I have just been printing my question, and then using an input function to make an input, but I'm wondering if there is a better way. Here is my code:

```
import time
import sys

def input1():
    input("")

def oneprint(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.05)

oneprint("Welcome. This is a very easy test. Do as you are told.")
time.sleep(3)
q1 = "\nLet's get started. What is my favorite color?"
oneprint(q1)
input1()
```

Comment: Doing your slow print separate from the `input()` is the only conceivable way you could do this.  You have absolutely no control over how `input()` displays its optional parameter.

Comment: Are you trying to `oneprint` the user's input?

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan Yep!

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to add the same for loop that requires c inside of your script in your input1 function, here is an example of how you could do such a thing:

```
import time
import sys

def oneprint(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.05)

def input1():
    inp = input("")
    oneprint(inp)
    

oneprint("Welcome. This is a very easy test. Do as you are told.")
time.sleep(3)
q1 = "\nLet's get started. What is my favorite color?"
oneprint(q1)
input1()
```

if you try this it will print the desired color that was answered by the player by getting the input and getting each letter and writing it and flushing it through the oneprint function.

Comment: What I meant is that I want to print the actual input question using oneprint, but thank you for your answer.

Comment: Your welcome! I will change my question to be more accurate here.

Answer (score 0):

This will display the input and `oneprint` it:

```py
import time
import sys


def oneprint(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.05)


oneprint("Welcome. This is a very easy test. Do as you are told.")
time.sleep(3)
oneprint("\nLet's get started. What is my favorite color?")
oneprint(input("\n"))
```

---

This will hide the input, and `oneprint` it:

```py
import time
import sys
from getpass import getpass


def oneprint(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.05)


oneprint("Welcome. This is a very easy test. Do as you are told.")
time.sleep(3)
oneprint("\nLet's get started. What is my favorite color?")
oneprint(getpass("\n>"))
```

---

Where `getpass` is a password formatted input

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. If anyone else is having this issue you should just do:

```
input(oneprint(Blah Blah Blah Your Question Here))
```